# Проблема с очисткой поиска и маршрутами Yandex Map JS API

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

У меня возникло 2 проблемы

1. Не могу понять как вызвать метод **clear()** у **SearchControl**, в документации нет примера
   пробовал делать так:

```
search = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    useMapBounds: true,
    noPopup: true
});
search.clear();
```

Появлялась ошибка **clear is not a function**
Подскажите пожалуйста верный вызов метода, чтобы результат поиска нормально очистить

2. В моем решении проекте подстановка начальной точки для маршрута в зависимости от того, какой регион выбрал пользователь. При этом при смене региона, вводе адреса и построении нового маршрута, данные берутся старые и приходится несколько раз нажимать на поиск чтоб это вылечить.
   Удаление маршрута не помогает, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема
   Вот код

```
ymaps.route([sklad,point]).then(function (rout) {
    if(router) myMap.geoObjects.remove(router);
    router = rout.getPaths();
    router.options.set({ strokeWidth: 5, strokeColor: '#002233', opacity: 1});
    deliveryData.distance = Math.round(rout.getLength()/1000);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(router);
});
```

Так же у меня возник вопрос, как при использовании метода **router.options.set** задать параметр масштабирования, чтобы весь маршрут был виден?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

1. Примеры применения методов есть в [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl.html#method_detail__clear). Сначала вы создаете экземпляр SearchControl (как у вас в коде), затем отдельно вызываете `searchControl.clear()`
2. К сожалению, по приложенному вами фрагменту кода ничего не понять. Попробуйте удалять проложенный ранее маршрут сразу после смены региона.
3. *>как при использовании метода router.options.set задать параметр масштабирования, чтобы весь маршрут был виден?*
   Лучше при создании класса multiRouter.MultiRoute добавьте ему параметр `boundsAutoApply: true`
   Область видимости карты будет меняться при каждом перестроении маршрута.

И правильнее было бы оформить каждый вопрос отдельным постом, так другим пользователям будет проще отвечать и искать ответы.